# json object value to select dropdown update using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json value like

```
var roles = { "roles":[
     {"role_id":2,"role_name":"admin"},
     {"role_id":4,"role_name":"QA"},
     {"role_id":3,"role_name":"TL"},
     {"role_id":5,"role_name":"user"},
     {"role_id":1,"role_name":"root"}
 ]}
```

above json value will be update select dropdown using jquery output like

```
 <option value="2">admin</option>
 <option value="4">QA</option>
 <option value="3">TL</option>
 <option value="5">user</option>
 <option value="1">root</option>
```

i m using this method

```
   var dropDownField = roles;
   if(typeof(dropDownField) === "object" && Object.keys(dropDownField).length) {
        $.each(dropDownField, function(key, data){
            console.log(key+'  '+data);
        });
    }
```

i getting output like

```
   0 [object object ]
   1 [object object ]
   2 [object object ]
   3 [object object ]
   4 [object object ]
```

Please help me to solve it

Comment: We are not a free coding service. What have you tried and where did you get stuck, before asking here?

Comment: There are tutorials all over the web for doing exercises like this. Stackoverflow also isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. If you have made attempts and they aren't working show what you have tried and people can help you fix **your code**

Comment: Loop through the `roles` array, then use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, i am asking solve the issue, not expecting free coding service, thanks for reply

Comment: Try to look inside the `data` objects inside the `each` and you might see how to fix this.

Comment: i got output what i was expecting, this is latest code if(typeof(dropDownField) === "object" && Object.keys(dropDownField).length) {
 $.each(dropDownField, function(key, data){
  k = data['role_id']; v = data['role_name'];
     option_html += '<option value="'+k+'">'+v+'</option>';
 });
} thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further @Rory McCrossan comment, A. You need tun `each` on the `dropDownField.roles` not on `dropDownField`. B. You can "collect" the html for each item in the array, then [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append) it to the `select`.

```js
var roles = {
  "roles": [{
      "role_id": 2,
      "role_name": "admin"
    },
    {
      "role_id": 4,
      "role_name": "QA"
    },
    {
      "role_id": 3,
      "role_name": "TL"
    },
    {
      "role_id": 5,
      "role_name": "user"
    },
    {
      "role_id": 1,
      "role_name": "root"
    }
  ]
}

var dropDownField = roles;
var html = '';
if (typeof(dropDownField) === "object" && Object.keys(dropDownField).length) {
  $.each(dropDownField.roles, function(key, data) {
    html += `<option value="${data.role_id}">${data.role_name}</option>`;
  });
}

$('select').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan and @Mosh Feu